# Auspicious time for tefillah when the bride is led down the aisle

Tags: sources-mekorot, wedding, chassan-groom

I heard many times that when the bride is led down the aisle, it is an auspicious for *tefillah*.

Does anyone know of a source for this?

Comment: Yerushalmi brachos by beginning r Yochanan says if only one will pray all day

Comment: I wonder if there is maybe some deeper understanding on the words 'Lecha dodi likraas kallah' based on your question